# Java Icon/ImageIcon .setIcon onyl works under awd conditions

Tags: java, jframe, game-engine

Im trying to make a simple board game in which when you click a button its image is set to that of the character you have selected.

This:

```
board[x][y].setIcon(Soldier.iconImg);
```

Does not work. It places a tiny white dot on the button and nothing else.
The Soldier.iconImg calls for an Icon from the Soldier class.

```
String name = soldier;
Icon iconImg = new ImageIcon("/Resources/"+name+"Img.png");
```

Now when i do this:

```
board[x][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Resources/soldierImg.png"));
```

It works fine.

I've found a bit of a way around the problem:

```
board[x][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon("Resources/"+Soldier.name+"Img.png"));
```

I am however still quite confused as to why the first method doesn't work while the second does. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: With the code you posted, there is no way to know what the value of the `soldier` variable is. All we know is that it's not "soldier". And that you don't respect Java naming conventions. And that you're using public fields. If you want help,post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: String name = "soldier" NOT String name =  soldier;